# Using GTK+ with Broadway

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, glade

I consider to use GTK+ with Broadway backend for development of device control application.
Device is with functionality similar to  broadband modem/router (I intentionally selected example which is familiar for all :-)  ).
Device should be controlled remotely via web browser.

My concern is about performance of such control. I'm afraid that Broadway may be a bottleneck.
Probably I'm wrong but even in simple pilot I built it looks not so good.

It will be very appreciated to have your inputs based on real experience.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Will multiple people be using the same instance of the program at once? If so, forget Broadway; it was not designed to be used by more than one person at the same time. What is the actual device interface you are using this for? Is the device going to be serving the broadwayd itself?

Comment: This is for single user. Yes, device is going to serve broadwayd itself.

Comment: You'll probably need to measure then; I can't say anything about broadway's guaranteed performance. Good luck.

Comment: Any further comments? Did the OP try this? I am interested myself.

Comment: Yes, I'm developing control application with this. Hard to say something about performance. But it seems I don't need too much.

Comment: I work with GTK+ via Broadway. I need to upload and save some file on local computer (which runs browser).
Can I do in this mode that and how ?

Answer (score 3):

I've used broadway to deploy gtk+3 apps for multiple projects - usually in cases where the client's desktop is locked down, or people are stuck on Windows. Broadway performs significantly better than VNC or RDP.

There are solutions to the single-user nature of a broadway application. For example, I've developed a partial solution: http://tesla.duckdns.org/transparent-proxy-for-broadway-gtk3-html5-backend/ ... if you want security, you need to implement a login page, cookie setting, and port redirection based on a cookie. The example code is commented as such. I've been meaning to complete all this, but every time I've done it, it's been in a highly custom way for particular clients - not something that I can really open-source.